# Hive using sum() over function error--Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to run this query which includes `sum(...) over(...)` function in Hive but shows error.
And I'm trying to use `select distinct` in a subquery, but it still doesn't work.

Is there an error in `join` function?

This is my SQL code

```
    select
c.driver_city_name,
c.driver_car_brand,
c.year,
count(distinct c.driver_id)over(PARTITION BY c.driver_car_brand,c.driver_city_name,c.year),
sum(c.upply_hr)over(PARTITION BY c.driver_car_brand,c.driver_city_name,c.year),
sum(c.work_hr)over(PARTITION BY c.driver_car_brand,c.driver_city_name,c.year)
from (
    select
    a.driver_city_name,
    a.driver_car_brand,
    a.driver_id,
    year(b.reg_date_cheling) as year,
    d.onlinetime as supply_hr,
    d.charge_time_length/60/60 as work_hr
    from gulfstream_dw.dw_v_driver_base a
    join (
        select 
        driver_id,
        reg_date_cheling
        from g_bi.t_brx_xinzheng_driver_diaodu_1
        where driver_city_id in (17,18,2,3,1,5,10,4,24,23)
        and concat_ws('-',year,month,day) BETWEEN '2016-11-19' and '2017-02-21'
    ) b on a.driver_id = b.driver_id
    join (
        select
        e.driver_id,
        sum(e.onlinetime) as onlinetime, --在线时长（单位：小时）
        sum(e.charge_time_length) as charge_time_length --计费总时长（单位：秒）
        from(
            select distinct
            concat_ws('-',year,month,day) date1,
            driver_id,
            onlinetime, --在线时长（单位：小时）
            charge_time_length --计费总时长（单位：秒）
            from gulfstream_dw.dw_m_driver_strategy
            where concat_ws('-',year,month,day) between '2016-11-19' and '2017-02-21'
            and onlinetime > 0
         ) e
         group by e.driver_id
    ) d on a.driver_id = d.driver_id
    where driver_city_id in (17,18,2,3,1,5,10,4,24,23)
    and to_date(max_success_strive_time) BETWEEN '2016-11-20' and '2017-02-20' 
    and concat_ws('-',year,month,day) BETWEEN '2016-11-19' and '2017-02-21'
    and a.driver_car_brand in (
    "奇瑞-E3",
    "吉利-远景",
    )
    group by a.driver_city_name,a.driver_car_brand,a.driver_id,year(b.reg_date_cheling),d.onlinetime,d.charge_time_length/60/60
)c

group by c.driver_city_name,c.driver_car_brand,c.year
```

But there is error:

> ERROR Type:SEMANTIC_FAILED Error while compiling statement: FAILED:
>   SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups.
>   At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for
>   circular dependencies. Underlying error:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 6:6 Invalid
>   column reference 'supply_hr'

If I leave out `sum over` function and just keep `count over` function, it runs successfully.

Comment: You've got a typo in there:  **sum(c.upply_hr)**.  That incredibly non-descriptive error means you've got a column name somewhere in your windowing function wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I missed 's' in 'sum(c.upply_hr)' when I typo in stackoverflow. And the code is completed but still has this error

Comment: can provide the create tables to replicate the issue?

Comment: You are using windowing functions in the SELECT clause _**and**_ a GROUP BY clause on the very bottom. Does that really make sense? And what do you expect Hive to do with that contradiction?